# How to get rid of appname.vshost.exe file?

Tags: windows-services

I have created a windows service following basically these instructions: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/simplewindowsservice.aspx

I install it with my installer and my problem is that when I start it and then take a look at the task manager processes I can see not only appname.exe running but also appname.vshost.exe.

Can someone tell me what is this vshost file, why is it there, and how can I get rid of it??? (It is not physically in my folder where the service is installed...)

Thanks a lot

Comment: That vshost process is a helper to display the dialog in Visual Studio.  If you don't have the project loaded in Visual Studio, you shouldn't see vshost.exe.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the properties of the Project, go to Debug tab and uncheck Enable Visual Studio Hosting Process. Then after you will not see the appname.vshost.exe annoying you.